# Setting to let mouse events pass through GUI application

Tags: unity, gnome, compiz, shortcut-keys, mouse

I am using compiz to make an app transparent. I would like to be able to click through the app as well.

Q:
There are any settings in the GUI (Compiz) or via CLI to be able to set up an application (based on it's class like in Compiz) to not capture mouse events and just pass through it, or even better to enable capturing the mouse when a key combination is pressed (ex: left ALT + left Ctrl + mouse click) ?

Use case:
I am watching a conference online (let's say Google I/O), I am setting the opacity of the video app via Compiz (CCSM) to be very transparent, and only increase it's opacity when there is something that I need to see, otherwise I just do other jobs in the background, and keep an eye on the video if something interesting appears. What I would like is to be able to click through the app, because sometimes I need to change the app position just to click something and it's interfering with my work-flow.

As far as I know I did this a few years back, but can't remember how, not even what I used, maybe I did it in E16 not Compiz/Gnome/Unity, but I just can't remember.

**Thank you**

Answer (score 1):

Compiz once had a plugin called "Ghost" which allowed you to do this, but due to recent changes (including an entire overhaul of the Compiz code), this plugin is no longer developed or supported.

For this reason, it is no longer possible to both have transparent and transient windows using Compiz.

Comment: not possible, or just not developed?